# PHP Syntax check not working - linter not working

Tags: php, atom-editor, lint, linter, phplint

### My php linter is not working from [Atom](https://atom.io) or the Command line.

CMD: `php -l <filename>`

> Result: No syntax errors detected in C:\example\path\file.php

---

Running:

- Windows 10
- php 7.3.11

---

Things already checked:

- yes, the file really exists
- liner is installed (version 2.3.1)
- linter-php is installed (version 1.6.1)
- other linters work fine
- path to php.exe is defined in the package and `config.json`

Comment: Linter tells you that everything is ok with your file. It works. Does linter's response look confusing to you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The liner was not working, I purposely added an error to check if it was working. Turns out the linter was not working because I was using short tags `<?` so needed to change a setting in `php.ini` for them to show

Answer (score 0):

Solution `short_open_tag=On` in `php.ini` was set to **Off** needs to be **On** for linter to catch errors if you are using short tags `<? vs <?php`.

**Hope this helps someone else.**